# What is the difference between the languages?

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

A). There exists a bi-implication between the languages $L_1 = \{ a^mb^n\mid m,n\ge 1 \}$ and $L_2 = a^+b^+$.

But as such no kind of bi-implication exists between the languages in part B)

B). Are the two languages $L_1 = \{a^m(bc^k)^n \mid m,n \geq 1\}$ and $L_2 = a^+(bc^+)^+$ same ?

No, the languages are not same and in fact the first one is DCFL and not regular while the second one is a regular language.

---

Can anyone explain why is this happening ?

Comment: Yes, they are the same languages.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin, One more query. If possible, Can you please tell me the difference between the languages $a^m(bc^k)^n$ and $a^+(bc^+)^+$ ?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin, As the same logic above, I think they are also same .

Comment: They are the same; however, many authors would probably not write $L_2 = a^+b^+$ but instead prefer something like $L_2 = L(a^+b^+)$.  This avoids the grammatical ambiguity of having $ab$ stand for both a word, and the language consisting solely of that word (which leads to very awkward statements like $ab \in ab$).

Comment: @ErickWong, Can you please check my above comment ?

Comment: @garrick Your definition is incomplete: what are the conditions on $m$, $k$ and $n$?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin, I am sorry for the inconvenience. Yes, m,k and n >= 1.

Comment: @Garrick Those two other languages are not equal (to clarify, my previous comment was directed at the two languages in OP).  Please edit your question to include this question, because it seems like you are secretly asking one as a way of asking the other.

Comment: @ErickWong, Okk, i'll do it. Can you please answer the difference ?

Comment: Consider the word $abcbc^2$...

Comment: @J.-E.Pin, This string belongs to second but not the first one. That's the difference.

Comment: @Garrick I should have been more specific.  I suspect your real question is "I think that $a^+b^+$ is the same as $\{a^n b^m\}$, but I have been told that $a^+(bc^+)^+$ is not the same as [...].  Can someone help me understand why the same logic doesn't apply to this second case?".  Your question should include *both* parts, as well as the implication between them which is what you really are confused about.  It's not appropriate to delete the original part of the question after people have already answered it.

Comment: @ErickWong, I'll edit again :)

Comment: @garrick You got it !

Comment: Thanks @Garrick!  Your edits will be of great benefit to future readers of this question.  Nice job figuring out J.-E. Pin's hint!

Comment: @ErickWong,Done !! From now onwards, I will really post a clear question. You may edit as well, if I am missing some information :)

Comment: @J.-E.Pin, Big thanks for the help :)

Comment: @garrick You're welcome.